# A doubt in the proof of "AC implies law of excluded middle"

Tags: axiom-of-choice, constructive-mathematics

i dont understand why axiom of choice is needed for the proof, since X is finite and (if i haven't misunderstand anything) we don't need axiom of choice to define a choice function for a finite set.

The proof: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Axiom_of_Choice_Implies_Law_of_Excluded_Middle

Comment: Duplicate? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970511/zf-set-theory-and-law-of-the-excluded-middle. The crux of the matter is that the the theorem is proved in a logic weaker than the classic logic.

Comment: The proof you reference is correct except where it says $X$ is finite (which is not actually relevant to the proof), The finiteness of $X$ is not constructively provable. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diaconescu%27s_theorem for some more information,.

Comment: @Martín-BlasPérezPinilla: it isn't really a duplicate, since it's about a specific problem with the proofwiki proof.