# Proof by contradiction and ZF set theory

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, riemann-hypothesis

The following is quoted from Sir Michael Atiyah's draft proof of Riemann Hypothesis, Section 5, stating that 'To be explicit, the proof of RH in this
paper is by contradiction and this is not accepted as valid in ZF, it does require choice.' Does this means that a proof by contradiction is only valid in ZFC, not in ZF, provided the assumption that Axiom of Choice can not inferred by the axioms of ZF?

Comment: Any proof or disproof of RH from ZFC is one from ZF.

Comment: Here is the claimed outline of the proof: https://drive.google.com/file/d/17NBICP6OcUSucrXKNWvzLmrQpfUrEKuY/view?from=timeline&isappinstalled=0 . In Section 5, paragraph 4, the author claims that the proof by contradiction requires choice. I interpret it as requiring the axiom of choice. In the wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory , ZFC is described as extension of ZF with controversial AC.

Comment: I think there is a confusion there. Constructive mathematics is usually done in a setting where the Law of Excluded Middle does not hold, so proof by contradiction is not valid. In many constructive settings choice fails, because the axiom of choice implies LEM in general (although in some constructive settings, choice is in fact a theorem). The thing is that sometimes any choiceless settings is called "constructive", but this is in a non-technical sense. I can only imagine this as the source of confusion.

Comment: Building off of @AsafKaragila's comment, the term "constructive" is actually a really dangerous one here. It can refer to: arguments not involving the excluded middle; constructions not involving the axiom of choice; or even (in older, primarily Russian literature) computable. And just for kicks, the closely-related term "constructible" refers to elements of [Godel's constructible universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_universe) which - just to make matters worse - satisfies choice! And all this ignores its common *informal* use as "explicit."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does this means that a proof by contradiction is only valid in ZFC, not in ZF, provided the assumption that Axiom of Choice can not inferred by the axioms of ZF?

No. It's not entirely clear to me what Atiyah is claiming, although I think that's the most direct reading, but that statement above is false. Moreover, we can *prove* in a precise sense that choice plays no essential role in the Riemann hypothesis, and that the "provided ..." bit of your question is unnecessary.

Specifically, the key points are:

- **Proof by contradiction is perfectly valid** in ZF. The validity or invalidity of proof by contradiction is an issue about the *underlying logic*, not the theory, and ZF and ZFC use the same underlying logic (namely, classical first-order logic).
- **It is known** that ZF cannot prove the axiom of choice (at least, as long as ZF is consistent in the first place); this was [proved by Cohen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_choice#Independence) *(following a much simpler proof, due to Godel, that ZF cannot disprove AC unless ZF is inconsistent.)*
- Most interestingly, **any proof of RH from ZFC can be turned into a proof of RH from ZF**, even if the original proof seems to fundamentally use the axiom of choice. This is a consequence of an [absoluteness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absoluteness): absoluteness theorems state that certain axioms (e.g. choice) can be removed from proofs of sentences which are particularly "simple" in form, and it turns out that [RH can be expressed in a sufficiently simple manner for an appropriate absoluteness result to apply](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31846/is-the-riemann-hypothesis-equivalent-to-a-pi-1-sentence).

Note that my second and third bulletpoints definitely require proof. They're absolutely (hehe) not obvious, and it's perfectly reasonable for mathematicians outside of logic to not be familiar with them (especially the third). That said, they do demonstrate that the set-theoretic concerns raised are void.

Comment: Thanks Noah, your answer, together with https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/970511/zf-set-theory-and-law-of-the-excluded-middle very much clear up my confusion.